# response a file from buffer, the request is made twice to be downloaded

Tags: javascript, express, file, buffer

I have an express nodejs server which does some calculations and creates a pdf file and sends it as the response. The problem is, when the user tries to download the file, the endpoint is called twice by the browser so the calculations are done twice and it will take twice as long and it will take around 20 seconds for the request to be answered. I checked and saw that the endpoint itself is called twice not favicon.ico or other things.

The file is not saved on the server and is created as buffer and then piped to the client. The endpoint is not called by the frontend code or fetched by something, it is just opened in a new tab in the browser. Some of the code is listed below:

```js
let buffer =  await createPdfBuffer() // a custom function that creates the pdf as buffer
const readStream = new stream.PassThrough();

readStream.end(buffer);
res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + file.pdf);
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
readStream.pipe(res);
```

Comment: I didn't understand your problem but I think using  a variable can help like setting its value to `var = done` after  the first request.

Comment: @K-J so then what is your recommendation to avoid that? for example get the file using fetch in frontend and then show it somehow in a new tab ?

Comment: my own assumptions are that the first request is made in order to get the file's size or type and the other one is for downloading and viewing it. so is there a way of sending these data so that the browser does not make the second request ?

Comment: @k-j yes and both of them require the file being saved inside the server, but i would like to generate it on the go